# на Ubuntu VPS: UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, unicode

Есть VPS на Ubuntu 20.04 (python 3.8.10) и мой пк на Win11 (python 3.11.2)
Один и тот же пайтон скрипт отлично работает на Win11, но на Ubuntu сервере выдает ошибку:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 143-148: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Проблему вижу в наличии русских слов в теле скрипта, но почему разное поведение на Win11 и Ubuntu я не понимаю.
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` в начале скрипта присутствует

Comment: Потому что на Ubuntu сервере не настроена локаль, например?

Comment: Что есть локаль, не понял?

Comment: Файл с исходным кодом сохранён не в кодировке UTF-8. Скорее всего вы его создали на Windows в кодировке Windows-1251 или UTF-16. То что в заголовке записан `coding` ничего не исправляет и не меняет. `coding` вообще не нужен если вы сохраняете файлы в UTF-8. В вопросе мало данных чтобы дать ответ. Только предположения и комментарии.

Comment: В том то и проблема что конретики не могу привести, код хоть print(‘привет’), проблема началась после обновления убунту с 18 на 20 и соответственно пайтона с 3.5 по моему на 3.8. На Убунту 18 этот же скрипт работал как часы

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy файл был действительно сохранен не в UTF, смена кодировки в PyCharm и пересохранение помогли, благодарю!